# how httpwebrequest.getrequeststream return instance of abstract class system.io.stream

Tags: c#, stream, abstract-class

System.io.stream is a abstract class then how httpwebrequest.getrequeststream() return the instance of stream class.
i.e

```
 Stream serverStream  = request.GetRequestStream();
```

How stream class is initialized?

Answer (score 0):

httpwebrequest.getrequeststream() returns one of the concrete classes that inherit from the abstract class System.IO.Stream.

Comment: "The GetRequestStream method initiates a request to send data to the Internet resource and returns a Stream instance for sending data to the Internet resource." this is what msdn says and its seems not returning the concrete inherited class like file stream or memory stream

Comment: Do a Debug.WriteLine of serverStream.GetType().FullName and you'll get the actual concrete class. MSDN indicates that it could be any of the concrete classes inherited from Stream (an instance of x mostly means x and any class which can fill in for x)

Answer (score 0):

**Stream** is the abstract base class of all streams.

The Stream class and its derived classes provide a generic view of these different types of input and output, and isolate the programmer from the specific details of the operating system and the underlying devices.

and

```
httpwebrequest.getrequeststream
```

Gets a **Stream** object to use to write request data.

You have to create an instance of stream subclasses to get initialized.

go through [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream(v=vs.110).aspx) and [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1404303/c-sharp-using-streams) for more .

Comment: The code in question is working code and i am not looking for initializing the stream class using subclass. my question is how the above code is initializing the abstract class

Comment: nope i had not created a instance i can't create a instance of stream class as its an abstract class using the new operator. so just wondering how this statement "Stream serverStream  = request.GetRequestStream();" is initializing the stream class

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing the type of a reference with the type of an object.

The fact that a method signature declares a particular type as its return type does not mean that instances returned will be of that exact type, they could be of a type derived from the one specified, as in you case.

Try this: `Console.WriteLine(stream.GetType())`, should clear your thoughts a bit.