# using C Pointer with char array

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, character-arrays

```
int i=512;
char *c = (char *)&i;
c[0] =1;
printf("%d",i);
```

this displays "513", it adds 1 to i.

```
int i=512;
char *c = (char *)&i;
c[1] =1;
printf("%d",i);
```

whereas this displays 256. Divides it by 2.
Can someone please explain why? thanks a lot

Comment: Please read [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21449/types-of-endianness) and [this wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) as the combination will likely answer everything you just asked.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Binary

The 32-bit number 512 expressed in binary, is just:

```
00000000000000000000001000000000
```

because 2 to the power of 9 is 512. Conventionally, you read the bits from right-to-left.

Here are some other decimal numbers in binary:

```
0001 = 1
0010 = 2
0011 = 3
0100 = 4
```

### The Cast: Reinterpreting the Int as an Array of Bytes

When you do this:

```
int i = 512;
char *c = (char *)&i;
```

you are interpreting the 4-byte integer as an array of characters (8-bit bytes), as you probably know. If not, here's what's going on:

```
&i
```

takes the address of the variable `i`.

```
(char *)&i
```

reinterprets it (or *casts* it) to a pointer to char type. This means it can now be used like an array. Since you know an `int` is at least 32-bit on your machine, can access its bytes using `c[0], c[1], c[2], c[3]`.

Depending on the [endianness](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) of the system, the bytes of the number might be laid out: most significant byte first (big endian), or least significant byte first (little endian). *x86* processors are little endian. This basically means the number 512 is laid out as in the example above, i.e.:

```
00000000 00000000 00000010 00000000
    c[3]     c[2]     c[1]     c[0]
```

I've grouped the bits into separate 8-bit chunks (bytes) corresponding to the way they are laid out in memory. Note, you also read them right-to-left here, so we can keep with conventions for the binary number system.

### Consequences

Now setting `c[0] = 1` has this effect:

```
00000000 00000000 00000010 00000001
    c[3]     c[2]     c[1]     c[0]
```

which is `2^9 + 2^0 == 513` in decimal.

Setting `c[1] = 1` has this effect:

```
00000000 00000000 00000001 00000000
    c[3]     c[2]     c[1]     c[0]
```

which is `2^8 == 256` in decimal, because you've **overwritten** the second byte 00000010 with 00000001

Do note on a *big endian* system, the *bytes* would be stored in reverse order to a *little endian* system. This would mean you'd get totally different results to ones you got if you ran it on one of those machines.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation, but I have only one thing left which is confusing me.. how is `code` (char *)&i `code` getting interpreted as 4-byte integers ?

Comment: It's not. It's interpreting the 4-byte integer as a set of bytes (char). Basically, you're taking the address of `i`, and then you *cast* it to a *pointer* to *char*. That means it can be interpreted as an array of bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Remember char is 8 bit, 512 is bit representation is
`512 = 10 0000 0000`

when you do `char *c = (char *)&i;` you make:

`c[1] = 10

c[0] = 0000 0000`

when you do c[0] = 1
you make it `10 0000 0001` which is 513.

when you do c[1] = 1, you make it `01 0000 0000` which is 256.

Answer (score 2):

Before you wonder why what you're seeing is "odd", consider the platform you're running your code on, and the [**endianness**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness) therein.

Then consider the following

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i=512;
    printf("%d : ", i);
    unsigned char *p = (unsigned char*)&i;
    for (size_t j=0;j<sizeof(i);j++)
        printf("%02X", p[j]);
    printf("\n");

    char *c = (char *)&i;
    c[0] =1;
    printf("%d : ", i);
    for (size_t j=0;j<sizeof(i);j++)
        printf("%02X", p[j]);
    printf("\n");

    i = 512;
    c[1] =1;
    printf("%d : ", i);
    for (size_t j=0;j<sizeof(i);j++)
        printf("%02X", p[j]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

On my platform (Macbook Air, OS X 10.8, Intel x64 Arch)

```
512 : 00020000
513 : 01020000
256 : 00010000
```

Couple what you see above with what you have hopefully read about [**endianness**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), and you can clearly see my platform is **little endian**. So whats yours?

Answer (score 1):

Since you are aliasing an `int` through a `char` pointer, and a `char` is 8 bits wide (a byte), the assignment:

```
c[1] = 1;
```

will set the second byte of `i` to `000000001`. Bytes 1, 3 and 4 (if `sizeof(int) == 4`) will stay unmodified. Previously, that second byte was `000000010` (since I assume you're on an x86-based computer, which is a little-endian architecture.) So basically, you shifted the only bit that was set one position to the right. That's a division by 2.

On a little-endian machine and a compiler with 32-bit `int`, you originally had these four bytes in `i`:

```
  c[0]      c[1]      c[2]     c[3]
00000000  00000010  00000000 00000000
```

After the assignment, `i` was set to:

```
  c[0]      c[1]      c[2]     c[3]
00000000  00000001  00000000 00000000
```

and therefore it went from 512 to 256.

Now you should understand why `c[0] = 1` results in 513 :-) Think about which byte is set to 1 and that the assignment doesn't change the other bytes at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's depends on the machine whether that is `little endian` or `big endian` that how data is stored in bits.for more read this about [endianness](http://williams.comp.ncat.edu/Endian.htm)

C language doesn't guarantee about this .

```
512 in binary :

    =============================================
    0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0010 | 0000 0000   ==>512
    =============================================
      12          34          56          78
```

(0x12345678 suppose address of this int)

```
char *c =(char *)&i now c[0] either point to 0x78 or 0x12
Modifying the value using c[0] may result to 513 if it points to 0x78
    =============================================
    0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0010 | 0000 0001   ==> 513
    =============================================

or, can be 

    =============================================
    0000 0001 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0010 | 0000 0000  ==>2^24+512
    =============================================
```

Similarly for 256 also : because your c[1](http://williams.comp.ncat.edu/Endian.htm) will have the address of 2nd byte from right.
in figure below,

```
    =============================================
    0000 0000 | 0000 0000 | 0000 0001 | 0000 0000  ==>256
    =============================================
```

So its implemention of representation of numbers in our system

Answer (score 0):

It's because your machine is [little endian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), meaning the least-significant byte is stored first in memory.

You said `int i=512;`. `512` is `0x00000200` in hex (assuming a 32-bit OS for simplicity). Let's look at how `i` would be stored in memory as hexadecimal bytes:

```
  00 02 00 00  // 4 bytes, least-significant byte first
```

Now we interpret that same memory location as a character array by doing `char *c = (char *)&i;` - **same memory, different interpretation**:

```
  00 02 00 00
c[0][1][2][3]
```

Now we change `c[0]` with `c[0] =1;` and the memory looks like

```
  01 02 00 00
```

Which means if we look at it as a little endian `int` again (by doing `printf("%d",i);`), it's hex `0x00000201`, which is `513` decimal.

Now if we go back and change `c[1]` with `c[1] =1;`, your memory now becomes:

```
  00 01 00 00
```

Now we go back and interpret it as a little endian `int`, it's hex `0x00000100`, which is `256` decimal.